# How to property set one-to-many relationship with code first?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Entity framework throws an exception when I try and save an object. Probably it's because of a **many to one** relationship and it doesn't know how to insert.

**Models:**

```
public class Photo
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public List<Tag> Tags {get;set;}
}

public class Tag
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string TagText {get;set;}
}
```

This works fine if i dont try and link two or more Photos to the same tag.

Example:

```
Photo photo1 = new Photo();
Photo photo2 = new Photo();
Tag tag = new Tag() { TagText = "#EntityFramework"};
photo1.Tags.Add(tag);
photo2.Tags.Add(tag);
_content.SaveChanges(); //Exception
```

Anyone know how to set this up correctly with code first?

---

**Update:**

Exception:
Additional information: Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'X' of the relationship 'X' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

---

**Update:**

Script generated by add-migration

```
 CreateTable(
            "dbo.Tags",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    TagText = c.String(),
                    Photo_Id = c.Guid(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Photos", t => t.Photo_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Photo_Id);
```

Comment: what is the exception message ?

Comment: You are describing a many-to-one relationship, not many-to-many

Comment: @Selman22 - Added exception

Comment: @Rui Thats what i meant... :P my bad

Comment: Do you use Model First/Code First/Database First? And if you use Code First, how do you define your relationships?

Comment: I'm using code fist, i run add-migration which creates table a tag table like this: Id, TagText, Photo_Id(foreign key to Photo.Id) I've updated the question with the generated script

Comment: With the above model you can only add every tag once to a photo. What you need is a many-to-many relationship, as shown in @Moho's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also define a collection property in `Tag` for many to many:

```
public class Tag
{
    ...
    public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```